# Block with two inputs in pgf/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I am trying to draw the following block diagram using pgf/TikZ. Actually I am struck at getting the two inputs to the first block horizontal.

[image: block diagram]

What is the best way to draw the above diagram using pgf/TikZ.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw,rounded corners,text width=2.5cm,align=center}]
\node[box] (a) {Psychoacustic Model};
\node[left=of a.170,font=\bfseries] (aux1) {Reference};
\node[left=of a.190,font=\bfseries] (aux2) {Degraded};
\node[box,right=of a] (b) {Cognitive Model};
\node[right=of b,font=\bfseries] (c) {Score};
\draw[->] (aux1) -- (a.170);
\draw[->] (aux2) -- (a.190);
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\draw[->] (b) -- (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What am I supposed to change in this code if I need to change relative vertical distance between the two inputs? what does a.170 or a.190 actually mean

Comment: a.170 and a.180 mean the angle from the center line of the a node. To increase the vertical distance, you could try, a.160 and a.200. To decrease the vertical distance, you could try, a.175 and a.185.  a.180 is the west direction.